# Express.js server not responding - how to debug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, express

I have a express.js API that i recently had to tweak for some frankly dumb changes that affected core elements of it.

Now I have the problem that sometimes my server doesn't respond and after changing ~ 15 API paths i can no longer backtrack and redo it without losing way too much time. I suspect the server somehow is stuck in a endless loop and is just busy looping trough infinity and not responding to anything else.

Is there any good way to debug this kind of bug? Can i e.g. log the line-number i am running every second?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug Node.js applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications)

Comment: How would that help? Did you just google for "how to debug" and linked it here? If not, please explain how this would help me find the exact line i am stuck? When i read this article i could not see how it would help me.

Comment: No, I did not simply google _how to debug_. From what you described, I strongly recommend you read up how debugging works and how it may help you. Have a look at profiling while you are at it. And maybe also start using version control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Visual Studio debugger to be able to see the call stack and current line upon pausing the process.

Comment: Very productive and useful comment right there @Yerken! `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 0):

You can debug expressjs by setting the environment variable DEBUG

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

If you want to show all protocols *express* uses internally set the environment variable DEBUG to `express:*` when you start your application

`$ DEBUG=express:* node index.js`

or *node-inspector* (https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), see this [Node-inspector with Express 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797931/node-inspector-with-express-4)